# Config file for Android App

Tags: android, eclipse, deployment, configuration, apk

I made an Android activity and deploy it to my device using eclipse. Now i would like to add a INI configuration file to it.

What would be the right place to install this file on the device ?

I want want this configuration file to be modifyable without having to open the project using eclipse so that someone without programming knowledge or developping tools could still be able to modify this config file.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the right place to install this file on the device ?

[External storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). It is the only place the user has access to.

You might package a template or starter version of your configuration file inside your app, such as in `assets/`, then copy that file to external storage on first run of your app (or if the user accidentally deletes or corrupts the copy on external storage).